# How can I change userRecordId in SoftLayer_Billing_Order record

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to change ownership of a SoftLayer device to another user.

The only way I appears to do that I would have to change the userRecordId in the `SoftLayer_Billing_Order record`.  I don't see an `editObject` method under SoftLayer_Billing_Order methods.

How do I transfer the owner of a SoftLayer device?

Comment: I can't use the REST API to change an order record userRecodeId. How can I change ownership of a device when the person who did the original order has left the company?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using the API, the order records cannot be edited.

Comment: Bummer, so how can I change ownership of a device when the person who did the original order has left the company?

Comment: Well You could try to ask to the softlayer guys by creating a ticket and asking them if they can change it, But I not sure if they can do it, because they want to keep the historical data of the order. I suggest you to set a tag to the machine such as "owner: username", in that way you only have to see the tag in order to know who is the owner of the machine